# Can 'filtered' be ambiguous?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity

I'm working with algorithms that filter their input (that is, remove part of it), and I'm not sure this phrase is unambiguous:

> This function returns the filtered elements.

Is it obvious that *filtered* here means *the elements that have passed the filter*? Or could it mean *the elements that have been filtered out*?

If both are present, I believe it's easier to eliminate the ambiguity:

> 1. This function returns a pair of lists *(filtered_out,filtered_in)* .
> 2. This function returns a pair of lists *(filtered_out,filtrate)*.

Buf if I see just a variable named *filtered*, without the *_out* and *_in* suffixes, I'm not sure which one should be inferred.

Comment: You obviously mean *filtered **set of** elements*, a set filtered from the whole. The (individual) elements themselves are not filtered as such.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194901/sieve-vs-filter-are-they-opposites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the original wording is ambiguous. Also I don't think "filtered *in*" makes sense, because we do not use the preposition *in* with *to filter*, but only the preposition *out*.

I would suggest that, to remove all ambiguity, you use expressions such as:

> ... those elements *that passed through* the filter.
>   ... those elements *retained by* the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Indeed "filtered in" seems quite strange, perhaps "filtered through" at best, but avoiding "filtered" at all seems to be a more reasonable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The 'filtered' elements could be assumed to be 'those elements hitting the filter(ing process).

I'd certainly use one of the ***three*** options:

> This function returns those elements previously filtered out.
>
> This function returns those elements not previously filtered out.
>
> This function returns all those elements previously having undergone the
>   filtering process.

Comment: I liked your suggestions and they might come in handy, but @TrevorD's formulations seem more concise and by avoiding using "filtered" at all, they steer clear of the issue. I do think "not filtered out" is a nice solution as well.