# Can "filter for x" be used in two opposite senses?

Tags: word-usage

Can "filter for" be used in the following sense:

"ABC is very important as it **filters for** high quality and reliable results."

Filter for has been used as filter out:

"8. to act as a filter for; to slow or partially obstruct the passage of." (The Free Dictionary)

I am aware that filter on its own is ambiguous; see [Sieve vs filter? Are they opposites?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194901/sieve-vs-filter-are-they-opposites)

This question is specifically about "filter for" and its second usage (where it's followed by the desired state).

Comment: Filters pass some stuff and don’t pass other stuff.  It’s outside of the filter’s domain to decide which is the important stuff.

Comment: 'Filter for' (ie to seek, find and present you with) is used quite widely. An internet example: << The OR operator ... Orange OR Juice ... will filter for mentions of 'orange' OR mentions of 'juice' within your results.... >> [[TRAC Keyword Filtering](https://intercom.help/pulsar/en/articles/2089410-trac-keyword-filtering-operator-guide)]. But I haven't found a dictionary picking this usage up.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Filter for has been used as filter out." You don't mention "filter out" in your question.

Comment: While *filters out* is common (meaning that the things that follow are rejected), I'm not aware of an opposite—such as *filters in*, which I've never heard, or *filters for*, which I find equally strange here (although that phrase is fine if it means the same thing as the ambiguous *filters*). I would say this: *ABC is very important, as it filters **out** low quality and unreliable results.* Keep the phrase that's common, and reverse the noun phrase.

Comment: Yes, "filter for" is ambiguous.

Comment: I think in a situation where you're concerned both with what is stopped and what is allowed, you'd say a filter "filters out" specific undesirables and "lets pass" the rest, or something similar. If you're talking about "filtering for" meaning selecting, then "filter for" something and "ignore"/"block" the rest.

Comment: Related: [Can 'filtered' be ambiguous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118087), [Usage of "filter in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599183).

Answer (score 1):

As per Lexico:

> **[filter](https://www.lexico.com/definition/filter)**: Process or assess (items) in order to reject those that are unwanted.
> ‘you'll be put through to a secretary whose job it is to filter calls’

It's fine to say **filter for** with the understanding that the filter is removing *low-quality and unreliable results*, as noted by @JasonBassford. You might want to consider this slight rewrite of your example sentence:

> ABC is very important filter for high quality and reliable results.

But again, this means that the filter rejects low-quality and unreliable results.